# По нажатию клавиши enter после ввода в поле input необходимо срабатывание нажатие кнопки Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

По нажатию клавиши enter после ввода в поле `input` необходимо срабатывание нажатие кнопки `Button`. Оно почему-то не срабатывает.

**PHP - код:**

```
<input class="header_nav_search col-md-4 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 ml-auto" placeholder="Поиск..." type="search" oninput="$('.header_nav_search').attr('value', this.value);" value='<?php echo $_COOKIE["mysearch"] ?>'>
        <button class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 header_nav_button_search ml-md-0" onclick="search_start()"><img src="img/search.png" alt="search"></button>
```

**JS-код:**

```
$('.header_nav_search').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    $('.header_nav_button_search').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: вы завязывайте использовать jquery и при этом писать дичь всякую в атрибутах а-ля oninput

Comment: ```<button type="submit" > .... </button>```

Comment: а почему нельзя в js коде сразу вызвать search_start() и в ней уже получить нужные данные?